# how to use versioning in bidirectional association Spring data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-data

Lets say I have bidirectional one-to-many association between Parent-Child, mapped as follows:

```
public class TradingAccount {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tradingAccount", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<UnderlyingPerTradingAccount> underlyingPerTradingAccounts;
  @Version
  private Long version;
}
```

and

```
public class UnderlyingPerTradingAccount {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  @ManyToOne
  private TradingAccount tradingAccount;
  private Boolean enableBuy;
  private Boolean enableSell;
}
```

now when i update a TradingAccount this exeception I get exception:

object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

Comment: Can yo share how you update a TradingAccount?

Comment: just i construct a Trading account object with a list of underlyingPerTradingAccounts objects (id= null ) and call save() method of TradingAccount repo